# Does every invertible skew-symmetric operator on an infinte dimensional real seperable Hilbert space have a cyclic vector? If yes give an example.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space, $T$ be an operator on $\mathcal{H}$. Then $x \in \mathcal{H}$ is said to be cyclic vector for $T$ if closure of span $\{T^nx: n = 0,1,2,...\}$ is $\mathcal{H}$.
The operator $T$ is said to be skew-symmetric if $T^* = -T$.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: I am not sure whether every invertible skew-symmetric operators have cyclic vectors, but there are some operators with this property. I am actually looking for an example.

Comment: The range of $T$ can be proper. For instance let $T$ be the $90^{\circ}$ rotation in the first two coordinates of $\ell^2(\Bbb N)$ (and annihilate every other coordinate). Then there are certainly no cyclic vectors.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please help me with an example of an operator having cyclic vector